# MS Word table Last row split - all possible solutions already tried

Tags: microsoft-word

I am really struggling with this table, and after searching the web and possible solutions here I still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.
Within the file there are two tables in two different pages. Both of them are similar size. The formatting of the pages is exactly the same. However within the first page the table stays as a whole, while on the second page it transfers the last row on a new page. I changed the settings in the Paragraph section, as indicated in a another post. The margins of the page are narrow, so there should be enough space for that last row, but it still jumps to the next page.

What am I doing wrong. I can post the file if required.

[image: Split table]

Comment: There are empty paragraphs in your footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see in the screenshot, before the last table row of the last page, there is a tab with a line break and another line break.

[image]

These control characters must be deleted.

It might also be helpful to merge the table rows into a new Word document and then copy them back into your template.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! It worked with some strange impacts. I deleted the tab line. I also created a completely new file, where I copied the first table. Then I press once the "enter" to get to the next page. When I want to copy the second table then either
- the table is copied on the third page (in a complete whole one page table, no breaks at all)
or
- when I remove that extra line, the table does not move to second page, as expected, but it completely overlaps the very first page.
Any ideas why can this be happening?

Comment: The paragraph mark following a table cannot be deleted. You can change the font size to 1 pt, though.

Comment: That did the magic, thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on help.info.de's answer:

### You have blank paragraphs in your footer taking up room.

[image]

These are not "Control characters" as such but [non-printing formatting marks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NonprintChars.htm). It is good that you are showing them on your screen.

Comment: Thanks, did that. And together with the suggestion from Charles Kenyon, the file finally looks as it has to. Yayy!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers